# Read li values and insert them in an array?

Tags: jquery

I have a ul with id ul1.  In the UL I have 3 li, each containing a textbox.  How do I read each and every li of the ul to retrieve the values of the textbox in the li and put them in an array?

Comment: Why should we bother answering your question, when you have accepted 0 / 11 answers. Are they all that bad?

Answer (score 5):

It's as simple as this:

```
var values = [];

$('#ul1 li textarea').each(function() {
    values.push($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Should be enough

```
 var values = $( "#ul1 textarea").map( function( )
 { 
       return $(this).val( );
 }).get( );
```